# OSX/postfix: Unable to send mail with PHP mail()

Tags: php, email, macos, xampp, postfix-mta

Some while ago I've installed XAMPP on my Mac OSX machine.
Without ever doing relative configuration myself, the PHP mail() function worked beautifully.

Since a few weeks, without any apparent changes, it stopped working.

It worked both with my own ISP and with one of my clients' ISP. Now it doesn't work with either so I suspect it's a local problem.
Also, the mail does make it to postfix, so I suspect this is not a XAMPP/PHP issue.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Recent postfix mail.log

```
Jul 11 10:20:57 MyMac postfix/master[9012]: daemon started -- version 2.5.5, configuration /etc/postfix
Jul 11 10:20:57 MyMac postfix/qmgr[9014]: 3D6271033872: from=<nobody@MyMac.local>, size=3061, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 11 10:20:57 MyMac postfix/qmgr[9014]: 6083B1033897: from=<nobody@MyMac.local>, size=3061, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 11 10:20:57 MyMac postfix/qmgr[9014]: 765E210338C9: from=<nobody@MyMac.local>, size=3061, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 11 10:20:57 MyMac postfix/qmgr[9014]: D981E1033892: from=<nobody@MyMac.local>, size=3061, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 11 10:21:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9016]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.79.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:21:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9018]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.79.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:21:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9019]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.79.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:21:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9017]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.79.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:21:57 MyMac postfix/smtp[9016]: connect to ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:21:57 MyMac postfix/smtp[9018]: connect to ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:21:57 MyMac postfix/smtp[9017]: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.45.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:21:57 MyMac postfix/smtp[9019]: connect to ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:22:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9016]: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.45.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:22:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9018]: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.45.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:22:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9019]: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.45.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:22:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9017]: connect to ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:22:57 MyMac postfix/smtp[9016]: connect to ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:22:57 MyMac postfix/smtp[9018]: connect to ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:22:57 MyMac postfix/smtp[9019]: connect to ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM[74.125.43.27]:25: Operation timed out
```

Update; here's some log of sending mail; (address removed)

```
Jul 11 10:23:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9016]: 3D6271033872: to=<email@removed>, relay=none, delay=3473, delays=3323/0.03/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM[74.125.43.27]:25: Operation timed out)
Jul 11 10:23:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9018]: 765E210338C9: to=<email@removed>, relay=none, delay=2683, delays=2533/0.02/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM[74.125.157.27]:25: Operation timed out)
Jul 11 10:23:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9019]: connect to ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:23:27 MyMac postfix/smtp[9017]: connect to ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM[74.125.43.27]:25: Operation timed out
```

sending to hotmail:
Here I get another message.

```
Jul 11 10:46:23 MyMac postfix/smtp[9069]: 355CD1033C4E: to=<address@removed>, relay=none, delay=150, delays=0.05/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.37.72]:25: Operation timed out)
Jul 11 10:49:42 MyMac postfix/master[9081]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jul 11 10:49:42 MyMac postfix/pickup[9013]: 3E90C1033CC5: uid=-2 from=<nobody>
Jul 11 10:49:42 MyMac postfix/cleanup[9082]: 3E90C1033CC5: message-id=<20110711084942.3E90C1033CC5@MyMac.local>
Jul 11 10:49:42 MyMac postfix/qmgr[9014]: 3E90C1033CC5: from=<nobody@MyMac.local>, size=3066, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 11 10:50:12 MyMac postfix/smtp[9084]: connect to mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104]:25: Operation timed out
Jul 11 10:50:42 MyMac postfix/smtp[9084]: connect to mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me looks like authentication...

I believe gmail only allow smtp relay with an authenticated account...

I had to follow this info to get it working in the past... http://herson.biz/?p=94

**EDIT**

IP may be blacklisted with them (and possibly other providers).

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe I'm not relaying the message.
What I try to do is to send a mail to a gmail address.

Comment: I'll add a log of sending a message to a hotmail address as well.

Comment: Sometimes you'll get funny behavior like that if the mailbox is full, or the ip your sending from is on some black-list.

Comment: I checked, my ip/isp is one some blacklists. I never sent any mails to another address but my own.

Comment: Openssl isn't working for me, not worth the time to spend another day trying to get this to work. 
I don't understand why this would suddenly stop working. Might be because of the blacklists, allthough I would expect the mail to land in spam or get bounced.

Comment: you will need to then try and apply to get it removed - most provide a process for doing so, but can take months if at all. But if it's shared hosting in any way, chances are someone has spammed from it.

Comment: they don't always get bounced... if they are nice they will, otherwise it's black hole :)

Comment: it's not shared hosting, I just want to be able to quickly send test emails from my (local) development machine.

Comment: No matter, if IP is black listed, unless you get it removed from gmail you wont be able to send to gmail ... same may apply to others. Do you have 'live' mailserver, you could send through it...

Comment: What I have done now is added the smtp server of my ISP to postfix's config. Now sending of mail works again.